# Parse SQLite ALTER, CREATE & UPDATE

Tags: javascript, regex, sqlite

My project involves running ad hoc SQL statements against a SQLite database. I'm looking for a JavaScript regex expression to parse out the ALTER, CREATE and UPDATE sql statements. Here's examples and the results I'm looking for.

## Create Index

```
CREATE INDEX Christy...
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS Christy...
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Christy...
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS Christy...
```

### Result

```
a = [..."CREATE", "INDEX", "Christy"]
```

---

## Create Table Without Table Constraint

```
CREATE TABLE Vicky (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,score REAL DEFAULT .10 CHECK (weight<=1));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Vicky (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,score REAL DEFAULT .10 CHECK (weight<=1));
```

### Result

```
a = [..."CREATE", "TABLE", "Vicky", "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT","name TEXT","score REAL DEFAULT .10 CHECK (weight<=1)"]
```

---

## Create Table With Table Constraint

```
CREATE TABLE Vicky (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,score REAL DEFAULT .10 CHECK (weight<=1)),PRIMARY KEY (id, name));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Vicky (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,score REAL DEFAULT .10 CHECK (weight<=1)),PRIMARY KEY (id, name));
```

### Result

```
a = [..."CREATE", "TABLE", "Vicky", "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT","name TEXT","score REAL DEFAULT .10 CHECK (weight<=1)","PRIMARY KEY (id, name))"]
```

---

## Create Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER Arwen...
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Arwen...
```

### Result

```
a = [..."CREATE", "TRIGGER", "Arwen"]
```

---

## Create View

```
CREATE VIEW Snow...
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS Snow...
```

### Result

```
a = [..."CREATE", "VIEW", "Snow"]
```

---

## Alter Table

```
ALTER TABLE Vicky...
```

### Result

```
a = [..."ALTER", "TABLE", "Vicky"]
```

---

## Update Table

```
UPDATE Vicky...
UPDATE OR ROLLBACK Vicky...
UPDATE OR ABORT Vicky...
UPDATE OR REPLACE Vicky...
UPDATE OR FAIL Vicky...
UPDATE OR IGNORE Vicky...
```

### Result

```
a = [..."UPDATE", "TABLE", "Vicky"]
```

---

Here's links to SQLite's docs for these SQL statements.

[ALTER TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)
 
[CREATE INDEX](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)
 
[CREATE TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)
 
[CREATE TRIGGER](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)
 
[CREATE VIEW](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html)
 
[UPDATE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html)

Thanks,
HeadDataZombie

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to parse them to validate accuracy?  Validity?  Security?

Parsing SQL isn't easy, and I doubt you'll be able to do it in a regex with that many patterns.   Perhaps [this link](http://regexadvice.com/forums/thread/39789.aspx) might help.   See also previous question [parsing-sql-create-table-statement-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060475/parsing-sql-create-table-statement-using-jquery) and notice mention of TrimQuery, which might help with the JS implementation.

If you're trying to log activities that these modification (CREATE/ALTER/UPDATE) statements are running, perhaps just creating triggers to insert into a logging table might suffice.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is hard (if not impossible) to parse with regular expressions. However...

The wierd diagram at the top of each page of the SQLite manual is actually telling you **everything** you need to know to use a parser generator like [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/) or [JS/CC](http://jscc.jmksf.com/) to parse your SQL statements.

For example, the following PEG.js code will parse an ALTER TABLE statement perfectly:

```
start = altertable

altertable = "alter" w "table" w ( dbname:identifier w? "." ) ? w? tablename:identifier w ( renameto / addcolumn)

renameto = "rename" w "to" w newname:identifier

addcolumn = "add" w ( "column" w )? col:identifier

identifier = chars:([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)

w = " " +
```

You do, of course, need to add the actions that build a parse tree.

Comment: I'm parsing the Alter/Create/Update SQL for a json project. I got the answer from RegexAdvice.com (http://regexadvice.com/forums/thread/77246.aspx)